# Count occurrence of a categorical variable, when grouping and summarising by a different variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table df that looks like this:

```
a <- c(10,20, 20, 20, 30)
b <- c("u", "u", "u", "r", "r")
c <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I would like to create a new table that contains the mean of col a, grouped by variable c. And I would like to have a column with the counts of the occurrence of b types within each group c.
I would therefore like the result table to look like df2:

```
a_m <- c(15, 23.3)
c <- c("a", "b")
counts_b <-c("2 u", "1 u, 2 r")
df2 <- data.frame(a_m, c, counts_b)
```

What I have so far is:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(c) %>% summarise(a_m = mean(a, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I do not know how to add the column counts_b in the example df2.

Giulia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using a little `table` magic:

```
df %>%
    group_by(c) %>%
    summarise(a_mean = mean(a),
              b_list = paste(names(table(b)), table(b), collapse = ', '))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  c     a_mean b_list  
  <fct>  <dbl> <chr>   
1 a       15.0 r 0, u 2
2 b       23.3 r 2, u 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `reshape2`. The output format may be more convenient to work with, each value of b has its own column with the number of occurrences.

```
out1 <- dcast(df, c ~ b, value.var="c", fun.aggregate=length)

  c r u
1 a 0 2
2 b 2 1

out2 <- df %>% group_by(c) %>% summarise(a_m = mean(a))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
       c      a_m
  <fctr>    <dbl>
1      a 15.00000
2      b 23.33333

df2 <- merge(out1, out2, by=c)

  c r u      a_m
1 a 0 2 15.00000
2 b 2 1 23.33333
```